# Shiro Subject filled with Pac4j?

Tags: shiro, pac4j

I´m wondering how the Subject from Shiro is filled with Pac4j ?
Normally I can use:

```
Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
```

I´m using Keycloak with Pac4j. It´s working and the user is authenticated.
But do I specifically set the Subject Object?

If I try to get the Subject object after successful authentication I still got `subject.isAuthenticated = false` ?

Or is Pac4J using another Subject Object?

Answer (score 0):

pac4j populates the Shiro subject thanks to the: https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j/blob/master/src/main/java/io/buji/pac4j/profile/ShiroProfileManager.java

Comment: Ok, thank you. But do I need to explicit call something like ```SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new Pac4jToken(Arrays.asList(profile), false));``` ? I´ve debugged and it seems  ```ShiroHelper.populateSubject(profiles);``` is never called during the logging process? Or add something in the shiro.ini ?

Comment: And also if I have ```jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm``` I got than ```Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jPrincipal cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jPrincipal is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.myapp.war' @7ae4e3f9; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')```

Comment: The logic is: the pac4j authentication process calls the specific `ShiroProfileManager` which calls `populateSubject` which in turn calls `SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new Pac4jToken(listProfiles, true|false));`

Comment: that´s what I understood, but if I set a debug point at ```io.buji.pac4j.profile.ShiroProfileManager``` and ```saveAll``` function or the constructor: 
The function is never called. Therefore my question if I need to initialize ```ShiroProfileManager``` or add some config in ```shiro.ini``` ? The ```org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager``` is called if I debug it.

Comment: And I customized the ```public class Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator implements AuthorizationGenerator``` ... maybe this is important... In shiro.ini: ```roleAdminAuthGenerator = com.myapp.Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator```

Comment: The `ShiroProfileManager` is automatically registered by the `FrameworkAdapterImpl` class. It's the `DefaultCallbackLogic` which will call the `ShiroProfileManager`.

Comment: Thank... and if I have a custom Callback Logic? My ```shiro.ini: customCallbackLogic = my.app.Pac4jForceDefaultURLCallbackLogic
callbackFilter.callbackLogic = $customCallbackLogic```

Comment: You should inherit from the original `DefaultCallbackLogic` to be sure that the `ShiroProfileManager` is called in the `saveUserProfile` method